# Multitouch with gestures on multiple composables in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I need to implement a collage module in my app and I'm struggling for days/weeks now.
I managed to reach a decent state, where I can tap, drag and pinch, but after pinching everything gets messed up.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BoxScreen() {
    val scaleButtonWidth = 14.0
    val boxes = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(
            Box(color = Color.Red, offset = Offset(0f, 0f), rotation = 0f, zIndex = 0f, scale = 1f),
            Box(color = Color.Yellow, offset = Offset(100f, 100f), rotation = 0f, zIndex = 0f, scale = 1f),
            Box(color = Color.Blue, offset = Offset(400f, 820f), rotation = 0f, zIndex = 0f, scale = 1f)
        )
    }

    var focusedBoxIndex by remember { mutableStateOf<Int>(-1) }

    var maxZIndex = boxes.size.toFloat()

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .noRippleClickable { focusedBoxIndex = -1 }
    ) {
        boxes.forEachIndexed { index, box ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset {
                        IntOffset(
                            boxes[index].offset.x.roundToInt(),
                            boxes[index].offset.y.roundToInt()
                        )
                    }
                    .scale(boxes[index].scale)
                    .rotate(boxes[index].rotation)
                    .background(box.color)
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .zIndex(box.zIndex)
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTransformGestures(
                            onGesture = { _, pan, zoom, rotationDelta ->
                                boxes[index] =
                                    boxes[index].copy(rotation = boxes[index].rotation + rotationDelta)
                                boxes[index] = boxes[index].copy(scale = boxes[index].scale * zoom)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            boxes[index] = boxes[index].copy(
                                offset = Offset(
                                    boxes[index].offset.x + dragAmount.x,
                                    boxes[index].offset.y + dragAmount.y
                                )
                            )
                            if (focusedBoxIndex != index) {
                                focusedBoxIndex = index
                                boxes[index] = boxes[index].copy(zIndex = maxZIndex)
                                maxZIndex += 1f
                            }
                            change.consume()
                        }
                    }
                    .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTapGestures {
                            if (focusedBoxIndex != index) {
                                focusedBoxIndex = index
                                boxes[index] = boxes[index].copy(zIndex = maxZIndex)
                                maxZIndex += 1f
                            }
                            boxes.forEachIndexed { index, box ->
                                println("$index: $box")
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                if (index == focusedBoxIndex) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.delete_image),
                        contentDescription = "delete button",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(scaleButtonWidth.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                            .offset(
                                x = (-scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp,
                                y = (scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp
                            )
                            .noRippleClickable {
                                focusedBoxIndex = -1
                                boxes.remove(box)
                            }
                            .border(BorderStroke(0.5.dp, LightGray), shape = CircleShape)
                    )
                    // top left
                    RoundButton(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.TopStart)
                            .offset(
                                x = (-scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp,
                                y = (-scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp
                            )
                    )
                    // top right
                    RoundButton(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                            .offset(
                                x = (scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp,
                                y = (-scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp
                            )
                    )
                    // bottom right
                    RoundButton(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                            .offset(
                                x = (scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp,
                                y = (scaleButtonWidth / 2.0).dp
                            )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    BoxScreen()
}

fun Modifier.noRippleClickable(onClick: () -> Unit): Modifier = composed {
    clickable(indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) {
        onClick()
    }
}

data class Box(
    val color: Color,
    val offset: Offset,
    val rotation: Float,
    val zIndex: Float,
    val scale: Float
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I feel I have tried pretty much everything